# asp.net dropdown list to open upwards

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a drop down list in asp.net and it opens downwards. I have repeater elements just below the dropdownlist and I have a mouse hover on the repeater elements.

So when I try to open and select items on the dropdownlist , my mouse technically gets to be over the repeater element , and I get to see the mouse over tooltip although I don't intend to.

To avoid the scenario , I would like to know if there is a way to make the dropdownlist open upwards ... it should then be called a dropup list I guess. :-) But I wanted to know if it is possible to get an asp.net dropdownlist to open upwards. Or if there is any other suggestion to solve my problem let me know.

Comment: Is there any way you know of to do this in HTML? Remember that ASP.NET controls simply produce HTML.

Comment: Yes instead of setting top:auto for the drop down menu you would use bottom:0 instead.

Comment: DropDownOrientation works too

Comment: @AnnArbor87, re: `DropDownOrientation` I believe that attribute is only on present Infragistics components. Re: `bottom:0;` that only works for a custom menu - not the standard Select element.

Comment: True, but anyways I think there should be a way doing it in the css.

Answer (score 3):

Since ASP.Net produces HTML, and the direction and position of the dropdown is left to the User Agent's discretion, you would not be able to control the direction using the standard form control.

However, you could replace the standard control for one implemented with custom positioning as demonstrated [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/).  Consider carefully the ramifications of such a replacement, as you would loose the niceties of the built in drop down control (Type to select, keyboard navigation, custom handling on mobile and touch devices) unless you re-implement each feature.

At a certain point, you need to make a design decision as to whether the labor and maintenance cost in making the drop down be a "drop up" is worth it.